# How to add support for mips to my docker buildx builder?

Tags: docker, mips32, docker-buildkit

I have created a buildx builder but it's missing `mipsel` support. I assumed it should support all archs `qemu` supports as well.

```
$ docker buildx create --name mybuilder
mybuilder
$ docker buildx use mybuilder
$ docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
[+] Building 6.8s (1/1) FINISHED                                                                                    
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                6.8s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                             5.9s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0                                                          0.9s
Name:   mybuilder
Driver: docker-container

Nodes:
Name:      mybuilder0
Endpoint:  unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Status:    running
Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

Why is `mipsel` (the architecture I am interested in) not in the list?

Comment: Hey @paulo did you ever find an sewer to this?

Comment: @AdamVanProoyen not really. Sorry. :( that task is pending on my list.